# How to use a window function in snowflake to look back 12 months

Tags: sql, function, window, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having trouble using window functions in SNOWFLAKE to look at historical data (from 12 months prior). When I add a dimension, this code doesn't work.

```
    SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',pl.DATE) AS MONTH,
COUNT(DISTINCT PL.ID) AS CURRENT,

    PL.DIMENSION,

    FIRST_VALUE(count(DISTINCT pl.ID)) OVER (PARTITION BY PL.DIMENSION ORDER BY MONTH ASC ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 12 PRECEDING) AS 1_YEAR_AGO
    from table1 pl

    
    
    group by MONTH, PL.DIMENSION
    ORDER BY MONTH
```

here are the results if i filter on the dimension:

[image: RESUTLTS]

i am wanting more rows.. for example month = 2019-10-01, CURRENT_ would be NULL and 1_YR_AGO should be 1 and so on.. what am I missing? (I put examples of this in the highlighted section of the picture. the results are unhighlighted.

NOTE: I've also tried a lag and it does the same thing here.

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results. I suspect `FIRST_VALUE(count(DISTINCT pl.ID)) OVER()` is not what you want - but I don't know what you want.

Comment: I’ve posted sample data if you click on the hyper link. And I show sample data (not highlighted) and desired results in yellow. I’m trying to do a lag basically, on 12 months

Comment: I’ve also tried a lag and it gives me the exact same results as these.

Comment: I saw the screenshot, but I'm still not sure what's the input data and what's the desired result. Please describe

Comment: What does "add a dimension" mean?

Comment: I’m counting the number of distinct ids per month.in the data, I’m filtering on just 1 id. This id was active from 9/2018 to 9/2019. We know this since there’s nothing before and after. That’s the current_ field. The 1 year ago field is trying to do a “lag” on the current_ field a year ago. So we have a 1 for 9/2019 because it goes back 12 months (count of 1), but it doesn’t have anything after for 10/2019, but that’s what I want. That’s the yellow highlight. Even those it wasn’t active in 10/2019, id still like the lag/window function to pull all the data for that id for a full 12 mnths

Comment: From how my colleagues use it, a dimension is something in our data structure that we can filter on. More or less categorical data. Think different product types.